# In Opencart 3 under PHP 8 how do I call module to show in another page

Tags: module, product, opencart-3

I have seen on this site the post re calling a module on needed page. I have tried to use this code to solve a problem. This code does not appear to work for me.
What I have is a module that places a label over each product depending on its status. It works well on products throughout site. However I have a module which calls all products on to one page. I want the label to appear on the products on this all products page.
[Banner on product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja3Xz.png)
The code I used in catalog/controller for the all product extension from previous post here was (382 is the label module number):

```
  $this->load->model('382');
$my_variable = $this->model_setting_module->getModule('382');
$data['any_variable'] = $my_variable['any_variable'];
```

On Template page:

```
 {{ any_variable }}
```

How can I get the module to be apply the label to the custom all products page?
As always help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create new module with name: "my_module" and you can call it in your "another_module" controller file:

```
$data['my_module'] = $this->load->controller('extension/module/my_module');
```

and in corresponding "another_module" template file you can retrieve it:

```
{{ my_module }}
```

Comment: Hi Thansk you for responding, I appreciate it. I have created the files as you indicated adding the code for the model to call: <code><?php
$data['my_module'] = $this->load->controller('extension/module/my_module');
  $this->load->model('382');
$my_variable = $this->model_setting_module->getModule('382');
$data['any_variable'] = $my_variable['any_variable'];
?></code> I have created an ocmod and imported both files. I am not a coder and there is no effect to the module created, which installed correctly. Can you advise what is wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: Now resloved by another coder directly.